# Is it possible to export a Kendo Grid to excel and attach that excel file to an email?

Tags: c#, .net, kendo-ui

Is it possible to export a Kendo UI Grid to excel and attach that excel file to an email?  I can export to excel with no issues but capturing the excel ouput is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: What do you mean "capturing the excel output"? It's a file. You attach it to an email the same way you would any other file. What exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: It would depend on which email client you are trying to use. It would have to be a client-specific solution. i.e. Outlook, some web-based client (Gmail).

Answer (score 0):

Sure, please see the demo on how to use excel export

https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/excel-export

Use ProxyURL for your controller. Then in your controller you can add the file as attachment to your email.